# Read vlan priority and write that priority in text file

Tags: kernel

I want to read vlan packet in such a way that it should read vlan Id and vlan priority and write it in text file. My text file having pairs like "vlanid vlanproirity".
 1. How do i read vlan id and vlan proirity?
 2. How can i write those id and priority into text file using c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Used socket programming for getting packet and reading clan tag.
2. Input and output function in c can be used here.